# Why annotation @JsonValue does not work in Jersey?

Tags: java, serialization, enums, jersey, jackson

I have RESTful service based on Jersey framework.

I need to serialize and deserialize some object which include enum fields.

I wrote two methods and annotated they with `@JsonValue` and `@JsonCreator`. But Jersey doesn't show enum fields?

My object with enum:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class RecipientWrapper{
    @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
    private Recipient recipient;

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private RecipientType type;

    public RecipientWrapper(){}

    public RecipientWrapper(String name, String address, Message.RecipientType type) {
        recipient = new Recipient(name, address, type);
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Recipient getRecipient(){
        if (recipient == null && name != null && address != null){
            if (type != null){
                recipient = new Recipient(name, address, type.toMsgRecipientTypeValue());
            }
            else{
                recipient = new Recipient(name, address, Message.RecipientType.TO);
            }
        }
        return recipient;
    }

    public void setRecipient(Recipient recipient){
         this.recipient = recipient;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return recipient.getName();
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return recipient.getAddress();
    }

    public Message.RecipientType getType(){
        return recipient.getType();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setType(RecipientType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public enum RecipientType {
        TO,
        CC,
        BCC;

        private static Map<String, RecipientType> nameMap = new HashMap<String, RecipientType>();
        private static Map<RecipientType, Message.RecipientType> msgRecipientType = new HashMap<RecipientType, Message.RecipientType>();

        static{
            nameMap.put("TO", TO);
            nameMap.put("CC", CC);
            nameMap.put("BCC", BCC);

            msgRecipientType.put(TO, Message.RecipientType.TO);
            msgRecipientType.put(CC, Message.RecipientType.CC);
            msgRecipientType.put(BCC, Message.RecipientType.BCC);
        }

        @JsonCreator
        public static RecipientType forValue(String value){
            return nameMap.get(StringUtils.upperCase(value));
        }

        @JsonValue
        public String toValue(){
            for (Map.Entry<String, RecipientType> entry: nameMap.entrySet()){
                if (entry.getValue() == this){
                    return entry.getKey();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public Message.RecipientType toMsgRecipientTypeValue(){
            for (Map.Entry<RecipientType, Message.RecipientType> entry: msgRecipientType.entrySet()){
                if (entry.getKey() == this){
                    return entry.getValue();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1'

compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.18.1'
compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:1.18.1'
compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-bundle:1.18.1'
compile 'io.swagger:swagger-jersey-jaxrs:1.5.0'

compile 'org.antlr:stringtemplate:4.0.2'
compile 'org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.22'
compile 'org.apache.velocity:velocity:1.7'

compile 'org.codemonkey.simplejavamail:simple-java-mail:2.2'

compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.12'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12'

compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
```

JSON Output:

```
{
  "address": "mymail@gmail.com",
  "name": "My name"
}
```

Why doesn't Jersey show enum fields?

Comment: Does making the inner enum type static make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `@JsonValue` annotation. If you remove it - it will work.

Example:

```
public class A {
    private String type;
    private RecipientType recipientType;

    public A(String type, RecipientType recipientType) {
        this.type = type;
        this.recipientType = recipientType;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public RecipientType getRecipientType() {
        return recipientType;
    }

    public enum RecipientType {
        TO,
        CC,
        BCC;
    }
}
```

When serializing it I get

`{"type":"a","recipientType":"BCC"}`

Jackson by itself knows to handle enums, you don't need to anything special for it. Add the `@JsonValue` just ruined it.

Comment: This is much less robust though, because it is sensitive to refactoring. Renaming any of the enum constants would break the API and shouldn't.